# How to create a window like Google Chrome in GTK+

Tags: c, gtk

I'm pretty new to GTK libraries and trying to develop a small project in GTK+2 with its C API's. The requirement is to do it in a **Google-Chrome type window**. It'll be having it's own title bar and controls with different colors.

Can anybody help me out with any tutorial or reference or any opensource code that already implemented this?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Should this also run on MS Windows or does it suffice when it runs on platforms on which GTK+ uses X-Windows?

Comment: At this point I am looking for Linux only. So MS Windows part is NOT needed. Thanks Oswald.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is custom decoration.

My understanding is that you have to set_decorated False on the window so that the WM doesn't add border/title bar itself to your windows and then have your own custom Window subclass that handles drawing it's decorations itself manually in the `paint()` method.

Not trivial.

Answer (score 5):

Since the Crhomium browser is an open source project, its source is available here: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/

What you seek should by definition be available there :)

Comment: What you've said is true @kigurai, but it's very tough as well as time consuming to search through such a huge amount of code without knowing the according technology very much. I'm basically a web dev who by chance got this stuff to do :)

Comment: @intellidiot It's inherently hard. Reading how other devs have implemented it is probably the quickest way to learn. There aren't any short cuts!

Comment: David is right, this is pretty hard. If you haven't done a lot of X and GTK+ stuff you could easily spend weeks and weeks screwing with this and still have wonky problems.

Answer (score 2):

what you might be looking for is the gtk wheelbarrow example. It shows you how to create a shaped window using an xpm file.there is an example in C, Perl and Python. I did one of these a few years back but haven't used it for some time now.

[Here is the C version](http://yofel.dyndns.org/trac/browser/c/gtk/tutorial/wheelbarrow/wheelbarrow.c)...

[The Python Example is Here](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/wheelbarrow.py)...

[Here is a tutorial on pixmaps and GTK+](http://pc.homelinux.com/docs/perlgtk/gtkperl-tutorial/tut-38.html)

Just create your image with Gimp and save it as an xpm file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused as to what you're actually looking for, but I think that what you want is a control that provides a web browser inside your window.

WebKitGTK+ is one such control: http://webkitgtk.org/

GtkMozEmbed is another: http://www.mozilla.org/unix/gtk-embedding.html

Last time I did this, I had to try a few to find one that worked. The controls have different bugs and support for HTML (and Flash.)

Comment: well, thanks for your time but all I'm interested in is a custom xwindow. Which will not have the desktop manager's title bars and borders. I used Google Chrome as an example. I do not need any web browser functionalities, but thanks for the links. Sometime in the future they might be needed, who knows :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to 246tNt's answer, Chrome uses Skia.  Here is an example (Gtk+ 3, cairo, skia):

```
  g_signal_connect(window_container_, "draw",
                   G_CALLBACK(OnWindowContainerDraw), NULL);

gboolean OnWindowContainerDraw(GtkWidget* widget,
                               cairo_t *cr) {                  
  SkBitmap bitmap;
  bitmap.setConfig(SkBitmap::kARGB_8888_Config, 100, 100);
  bitmap.allocPixels();

  SkDevice device(bitmap);
  SkCanvas canvas(&device);
  SkPaint paint;
  SkRect r;

  paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
  r.set(10, 10, 20, 20);
  canvas.drawRect(r, paint);

  cairo_surface_t* surface = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(
      (unsigned char*)bitmap.getPixels(), CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,
      bitmap.width(), bitmap.height(), bitmap.rowBytes());
  cairo_surface_mark_dirty(surface);
  cairo_set_source_surface(cr, surface, 0, 0);
  cairo_paint(cr);

  return FALSE;
}
```